# Phpize under Windows

Tags: php, windows, pear, php-extension

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://code.google.com/p/php-sweph/wiki/build to compile a PHP extension. My OS is Windows XP.

I'm unable to find "phpize" to do the command. However, I've installed Pear for PHP. is it something only for Linux or is there a way to compile with phpsize with Windows?

Comment: PEAR has nothing to do with PHP extensions. What you need is a C compiler such as Microsoft Visual Studio. Do you have one? Do you know how to use it?

Answer (score 7):

In windows compile script design to compile php itself and should add your extension to compile with php ...

> On Windows, you don't call phpize but instead you call buildconf.bat.
>
> Open a Visual Studio developer command prompt (either 64 or 32 bit),
>   and run
>
> cd C:\php-src buildconf.bat --add-modules-dir=C:\MyPhpExtensions
>   buildconf.bat will scan each subfolder of C:\MyPhpExtensions looking
>   for config.w32 files.
>
> It will then generate a configure.bat.

You can read more here:
[Compile an extension on Windows](http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/build-php-extension-on-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to build PHP extensions on Windows yourself.: You need a PHP build environment on Windows, which means you need Visual Studio and some other things. See http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.building.php for more information.

It's probably the easiest way to simply use Linux (or a Linux Virtual Machine), or get a pre-built .dll file form someone else.