# How to use konto_check library with php?

Tags: php

Has anyone tried using konto_check (http://sourceforge.net/projects/kontocheck/) with php and test-run it in your local machine?

I have searched far and wide on how to do this but all I get are some docs in languages I do not understand (it could probably in dutch or german).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading I found that PHP libraries are hidden in file `mini.zip`

Also I found in doc (yes, it is German):

```
Installation der PHP-Version:

phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

But I am not sure if it is necessary.

I hope that helps.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php
[how to install and run phpize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-install-and-run-phpize)

Comment: thanks for your response @Fazovsky. yes, found mini.zip too. i've placed the entire folder under my www folder, extracted mini.zip, tried opening /mini/mini.php in the browser, but it only prints the exact codes. am i missing something?

Comment: I've just checked the content of the file. It is just a test page, where you should be able to test how the library works. (i.e. it tests some functions like: `kto_check_blz`, `kc_html`, `lut_name`. It can help you to see how to use it once you import this into your project. If you can't see it working (only code) then the file didn't hit your PHP processor (should it be copied to www server?). Other thing is how to import this. I think the commands from my answer should help you.

Comment: this would sound so foolish. but i dont know how to run that command you just commented. :(

Comment: See 2 links I've added as a starting point.

Comment: can i do/run this using a windows machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999718/phpize-under-windows

Comment: this seems to be a lot work. thank you for your time man. i'll mark your answer as accepted.