# How to PHPize in windows?

Tags: php, dll, shared-libraries, phpize

I have to phpize the following two modules:

https://github.com/mgp25/curve25519-php

https://github.com/allegro/php-protobuf

I am able to phpize them and create respective .so. Is there a way to use phpize in windows to get respective .dll?

Comment: Been asked before.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15999718

Comment: seen that question, no good answer there. At least not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to install and run phpize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108937/how-to-install-and-run-phpize)